# Cant make dom manipulation work when making a changeBackgroundColor program

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was practicing my js since ima beginner and was trying to make a program to change the background color but whenever I was trying to use dom-manipulation nothing happened if anybody knows why that happens I would be very thankful.

HTML source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="button-style">
    <button class="button">Click me!</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body{
background-color: red;
}

.button{
background:transparent;
}
```

Js script:

```
const button = document.querySelector('.button')
const body = document.querySelector('body')
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'purple']

body.style.backgroundColor = 'violet'
button.addEventListener('click', changeBackground)

function changeBackground(){
const colorIndex = parseInt(Math.random()*colors.length)
body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]
}
```

Comment: Because your `<script>` element is located **before** the `<button>` element the `querySelector` call will return `null` because the HTML parser hasn't parsed the `<button>` yet. So you need to either add `defer` to your `<script>` or run your script after `DOMContentLoaded` the event.

Comment: First off: Nice work, because the code **does** work correctly when you include the script correctly. :-) Whenever you're doing browser-based development, be sure to have the devtools console open (or at least open it when things don't work). In this case, you'd have gotten an error about trying to use `addEventListener` on `null`, because `button` is `null` when you go to do that, because of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) (covered in the other questions' answers as well).

Comment: Thank you all so much i have now fixed my issue!